# sd-card - How to fix locked sd card

Tags: sd-card

I've a sd card on my phone, it's some type of freez , I could not do any thing on it , when I remove files , it removes and then come back to what it was , it's not formatting.

it freeze and nothing works on it .

What I've tried so fa : 
1- tried diskpart in cmd and change readonly and it's not write protected I think .

What should I do ? How can I save this sd card ?

Answer (score 3):

two possibilities, first is that being a hardware thing, as micro SDHC have a little notch you can easily notice which matches another notch in the reader and that basically just enables it in read-only mode. That you can't change, just try to use another reader or you could put a piece of silicon or tape on notch, easiest thing is to use another reader.

Second possibility is that being a file permission issue, in which case you can do the following : In terminal, use these commands:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

This will launch nautilus in root shell and bypass all permissions. OR:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will give you a list of the drives on your system, figure out which drive it is in the list, easiest way is to look for the blocks as this is the space. It will probably be /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc, then

```
sudo chown -hR <your username> <the SDHC drive, /dev/sdb for example>
```

this will change ownership of the drive to you. OR:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <the SDHC drive, /dev/sdb for example>
```

Though if you just execute the first command sudo nautilus it will save you all this trouble, but you'll have to do it every time you use the SDHC.

If all of this doesn't work, use this command :
sudo mount --options remount,rw

Comment: @RajeshThanks for the reply , I've windows, What are the comments for windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linux computer with an SD/MMC card reader, try running

```
sudo sdtool /dev/mmcblk0 unlock
```

Note that you need an MCC device (not a USB mass storage device) for this to work.

`sdtool` can be found [here](https://github.com/BertoldVdb/sdtool).

Comment: it also could be a fake sdcard, try running f3probe n it